# AFNetworking application/json

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

Using iOS, I'm trying to communicate with a webservice that requests 3 headers followed by JSON POST data.

I've taken a look at the following AFNetworking snippet which converts a Dictionary to a JSON file.  In this case I'm trying to POST both the headers and a JSON file.  Let me know if you have any suggestions:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:WalletKit_URL];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
NSDictionary *params = @{@"brand-id" : Brand_Id, @"api-key" : API_Key, @"Content-Type" : @"application/json"};
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:params];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}];
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the HTTP header fields to the `NSMutableURLRequest`.

```
[request addValue:@"foobar" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Foo-Bar"];
```

Comment: Thanks!  If my only data outside of the header is the JSON file, what command struture do I use to add it to the request.  I'm assuming that this is in lieu of the existing NSDictionary *params?

Comment: Yes, skip the params. If the JSON file is the only thing you're posted, you shouldn't use params, since that'll give you a form-encoded POST body (which looks like a query string, except it's in the body of the request). Use `setHTTPBody:(NSData)` to add your JSON file.

Comment: Is this what you were thinking.  I'd convert the JSON dictionary to a NSData file:

Comment: Exactly. Convert to an NSString first, and then use [NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] to convert to NSData.

Comment: Thanks.  Would it be simper to convert the JSON dictionary to data using NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error?